# Iptables Rules for Internet Access

Tags: python, user-interface, iptables, archlinux

Having System with 2 network cards. Anyone helps for iptables rules.

WAN interface IP address 192.168.1.10 and LAN interface IP address 192.168.10.1

Comment: Administration of a firewall is not a programming topic and therefore off-topic on SO.